# Search function, not working

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I am unable to see the results I asked for, it also randomly displays the posts I didn't intend to search. Help would be greatly appreciated.

This part of the code seems to work

```
if (isset($_POST['submitSearch'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['searchEnter']);
    $search = htmlspecialchars($search);
    //$postcommentidGet = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);        

    if (empty($search)) {
        header("Location: ../search.php?search=empty");
        exit();
    }
```

I may have done something wrong with the query

else {

```
    $username=$_SESSION['u_uid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (posts_title LIKE '%".$search."%'') OR (posts_content LIKE '%".$search."%')";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

This part of the code seems okay

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            // output data of each row

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {




            echo' 




                   <div class="searchResults">

                   <p>'.$row['posts_title'].'  '.$row['posts_content'].'</p><br>
                   </div>



                   ';
               }
    }




    //exit();
                }




} else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

}

Comment: Don't quote columns/tables. You also should parameterize the query, and possibly look into using full text searching. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: No way to help without more specifics.  Also, this sure looks like WordPress - if so, you should use the built-in `$wpdb` functions, not roll your own mysqli_ functions.

Comment: I updated my question, please try checking it out, thanks.

Comment: I now understand, thank you for the link, sir chris85!

Comment: @JustineLanceT.Mojal Great, so you are all set here?

Comment: You also shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` on your query unless you stored it in the DB like that.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Will remove htmlspecialchars.